# Structure of a bijection on a set of bitstrings to itself

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be the set of bitstrings of length $n$. Let $f:S\to S$ be a bijection defined as follows. Let $x\in S$, then $f(x)=y$ where $y$ is constructed from $x$ by

1. Adding all the $n$ bits of $x$ modulo $2$ and appending it to $x$
2. Popping the first bit of $x$

For example $f(1010)=0100$.

> Let $W(x)$ be the Hamming weight of $x\in S$ i.e. number of ones in $x$. It is clear that $f$ maps $x$, such that $W(x)=w$, to bitstrings whose weights are $w,w+1$ or $w-1$. I am trying to find for a given $n$ and $w$, how many of the bitstrings $x$, s.t. $W(x)=w$, are mapped to bitstrings of weight $w,w+1,w-1$ under $f$?

Looking at a few $n$, it looks like for small $w$, the mappings to weight class $w+1$ are more than that of weight class $w-1$ and for $w=n/2$, the mappings to weight class $w+1$ is equal to weight class $w-1$. But I couldn't prove it precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in S$, and let $x_1$ be the first bit of $x$. It’s not hard to verify that

- $W(f(x))=W(x)$ iff $W(x)\equiv x_1\pmod2$;
- $W(f(x))=W(x)+1$ iff $W(x)$ is odd and $x_1=0$; and
- $W(f(x))=W(x)-1$ iff $W(x)$ is even and $x_1=1$.

Assume that $n\ge 2$. Then there are $2^{n-2}$ bit strings of length $n-1$ whose Hamming weight is even and $2^{n-2}$ whose Hamming weight is odd, so there are altogether $2^{n-1}$ $w\in S$ such that $W(w)\equiv w_1\pmod2$. In other words, half of the $2^n$ strings in $S$ satisfy $W(f(w))=W(w)$. Half of the remainder, or $2^{n-2}$ bit strings, have $W(w)$ odd and $w_1=0$, and the other half, or $2^{n-2}$ bit strings, have $W(w)$ even and $w_1=1$.

For strings $x$ of a given weight $w$ matters are more complicated. If $w=0$, then $f(x)=x$. If $w=n$, then $W(f(x))=n$ if $n$ is odd, and $W(f(x))=n-1$ if $n$ is even. Suppose that $0<w<n$.

- There are $\binom{n-1}w$ bit strings $x$ of weight $w$ with $x_1=0$; for these we have $W(f(x))=w$ if $w$ is even, and $W(f(x))=w-1$ if $w$ is odd.
- There are $\binom{n-1}{w-1}$ bit strings $x$ of weight $w$ with $x_1=1$; for these we have $W(f(x))=w$ if $w$ is odd, and $W(f(x))=w+1$ if $w$ is even.